# LDAP (MSAD) role mapping caching behavior of ClickHouse server

Tags: clickhouse

Version 23.3.1.2823

LDAP role mapping is configured like [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/external-authenticators/ldap) against MSAD (Windows Server 2019).
`verification_cooldown` is not set.
`mytable` access is granted to a role only.
A user is member of AD group with the same name as CH role.

```
SELECT COUNT (1) FROM mytable
SHOW CURRENT ROLES
```

SELECT works ok, the role is in the output of the 2-nd command. I get the same result of these commands either with clickhouse-client and curl.

When I run these commands continuously and then remove the user from AD group, `SELECT` still doesn't return `Not enough privileges` and the role is still in the output. It may last forever. When I stop these continuous calls for some time (~ 10-15 minutes), I get expected output finally - error on `SELECT` and empty output of the last command.

It's interesting, that it looks like such a caching is maintained per host / client by the server. If I run the same statements from another host (while running them on the 1-st one continuously ) as the same user, I get different results.

Questions:

1. Is this expected behavior - having in fact some LDAP group membership cache which may not be purged forever, if I continuously run commands from this client?
2. Is this documented somewhere?
3. How to adjust this time interval of purging the LDAP group membership cache?

Comment: not sure it documented behavior, it looks like bug

Comment: Actually I'm trying to reproduce much more serious problem - a huge growth of tcp & http connections with many of them in a CLOSE_WAIT state. It looks like described [here](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/42644), but without success yet. The problem appears (unfortunately not on my test system with the same version), when a user running queries is added/removed to/from MSAD group mapped to a CH role. The problem described in my question is just a funny side effect...